# Limit search to Pages only

Tags: search, search-results

Is it possible to limit the search point search control to only show results that are considered 'Pages'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, actually you could use the STS_Content_class with the value of "STS_ListItem_850": // Page in a Pages Library either in the Core Search Results or by creating your own Search Scope.

Comment: I assumed by PAGES you mean the Pages library in the Publishing Site! There is also the :isDocument value for any kind of document (pages included)

Comment: Yeah i meant the Pages Library. But this also may come in handy, thanks.

Comment: Where is the best place to declare the "STS_Content_class"?

Comment: It all depends on your use, as I mentioned you could use it in your Search Scopes, or directly in your Core Search Results web parts in pages where you use them

Comment: Is it possible to set it in the default search page 'osssearchresults.aspx'?